# Hyper-V Ehnanced Session: Ubuntu 18.04 .profile not run

Tags: hyper-v, ubuntu-18.04, .profile

When I log in to my Ubuntu 18.04 VM using the Hyper-V enhanced session, my `.profile` is not sourced. So my custom changes to `PATH` etc. are not available.

When I log in via a basic session, `.profile` is sourced as expected.

How can I force sourcing `.profile` when I use Hyper-V enhanced session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh to make it work:

```
if test -r ~/.profile; then
        . ~/.profile
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Hyper-V uses `xrdp` to create the "enhanced session" with Ubuntu. There's a [question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92333/ubuntu-has-a-different-path-when-accessed-over-xrdp-session) where the OP says they are having `$PATH` issues over XRDP sessions. I believe the answer there may help you with your issues.

In short, you need to edit `/etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman` and make sure that the correct files are set in there. In your case, you'd add your `.profile` file, probably something like this:

```
session        required    pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/home/username/.profile
```

Or wherever your .profile is. You may also want to add the default `/etc/environment` if it's not already there as that is where the system's default `$PATH` is stored.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it did not work, the session did not load at all with the line in /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman. But it did point me in the right direction.